# Argument out of range while List.RemoveAt

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've got a list calles `BuildPositions`. When I try to remove just one, it deletes the whole list and gives me the error: Argument is out of range.

```
// Update is called once per frame
public void FixedUpdate ()
{
    if (Sex)
    {
        if (House == null && Money >= 1500)
        {
            GameObject Builder = GameObject.FindWithTag("Builder");
            int LuckyHouse = Random.Range(0,Builder.GetComponent<BuildPoints>().BuildPositions.Count);
            Builder.GetComponent<BuildPoints>().BuildPositions.RemoveAt(LuckyHouse);
            House = Builder.GetComponent<BuildPoints>().BuildPositions[LuckyHouse];
            Money = Money - 1500;
            GameObject HouseWall = House.transform.Find("Road_wall_Builder").gameObject;
            GameObject House1 = House.transform.Find("House_1").gameObject;
            HouseWall.active = false;
            House1.active = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure it isn't running over and over and deleting an item in the list until there are none left?

Comment: Yes it was! Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, it is not recommended to use FindWithTag, but instead creating a public variable and assigning the gameobject to it in the inspector. Same with transform.Find. To me it looks like your script is not functional either, because you remove **LuckyHouse** from the BuildPositions array, but then try to access it on the next line. You should reverse the order of these so you access the variable before deleting it.

Comment: I moved this line to the end of the function, that worked!
Builder.GetComponent<BuildPoints>).BuildPositions.RemoveAt(LuckyHouse);
You're right about my way of coding, i will work on that! thanks you!

Comment: I would also recommend assigning a variable to Builder.GetComponent<BuildPoints>() instead of calling the method several times. @Yvoro